# How to extract a link from an html file using bash

Tags: php, html, bash, curl, hyperlink

I am trying to create a shell file that will grab all of the images from the toplist of `wallbase.cc`.  So far I have it so that it curls the html code (`using mac so no wget`), and grabs all the links to the images.  The only problem I am having is that when I grep for the links it returns `<a href=link> <target=blank>`.  What I am trying to do is extract the link so that I can curl it into a file.  I thought about using an external Java or C file to extract the links but I figure there is a pure bash way to do it.

Any help would be great.

edit: my commands so far

grep `<a href="http://wallbase.cc/wallpaper/' wallbase.source`

This returns all of the links including the html code.
I just need to pipe this with some command in order to strip the html and leave the links

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you post the commands that you've tried so far?

Comment: Ive tried using sed and awk and even regex patterns but with no success

Comment: People will be able to help you out better if you post the actual, specific commands you have tried.

Comment: Appreciate the help, I have included my commands so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all of that with your native grep

This options may just be what you are looking for [grep's man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep):

-E, --extended-regexp
  Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)

-o, --only-matching
  Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

```
curl <URL> | grep -o -E "href=[\"'](.*)[\"'] "
```

The regular expression is extremely generic but you may be able to refine it to your needs

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for and no need to use any third party scripts.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single command:

```
mech-dump --links http://domain.tld/path
```

This command comes with perl module [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize)